# How to fix a corrupted MediaWiki page?

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-templates

One of our templates seems corrupted. We can't edit the page, even not show (yes, it exists) and so on. All this results in a time-out. Now we try to import a back-up version but also Special:Import gives a time-out.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:DeleteBatch.php Since you have a back-up to import again...

Comment: Just add `?action=edit` to the url.

Comment: @Tgr, I already did, same problem.

Comment: @DanielMK Thanks! Deleted now. But same problem with Special:Import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed (sort of), see https://sourceforge.net/p/semediawiki/mailman/message/36137641/ for details.